# SQL Server 2008 : how to back up database by query

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-backups

I was studying SQL Server and I got a question about about creating queries for backing up database.

I knew that SQL Server 2008 has function to create a `.bak` file.

However, I am not sure if I can generate the queries for whole database.

In SQL Server 2008, do they have function to generate the queries for backing up whole database ?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate the script yourself just setup a backup like normal but instead of clicking the normal button to start in the top left corner there is a script option
[image]

See the [backup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186865.aspx) command for more advanced options